# Flask - relationship with two tables

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a one to many relationship between two tables and I am having some issues with that.

**Tables code**

```
class Movies(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'movies'
  id = db.Column(db.String(300), primary_key=True)
  cat_id = db.relationship('Category', backref='movie')
  title = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
  link = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
  duration = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
  thumb_large = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
  thumb = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
  embed = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
  tags = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
  published = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)


class Category(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'category'
  id = db.Column(db.String(300), db.ForeignKey('movies.cat_id'), primary_key=True)
  category = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
```

I'm trying to migrate it but it give me this error  `sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedColumnError: Could not initialize target column for ForeignKey 'movies.cat_id' on table 'category': table 'movies' has no column named 'cat_id'`

I can't understand why this is happening if I already set the relationship.
Any idea what should I do?

Comment: this will [help](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/) you, create a column with cat_id name and in movies class define nature of the relatition

Answer (score 0):

I think that should fix it.
In my opinion the documentation of SQLAlchemy regarding relationships is very helpful. You can find this [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many).

```
class Movie(Model):
  __tablename__ = 'movies'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  title = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)
  link = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
  duration = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
  thumb_large = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
  thumb = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
  embed = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
  tags = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
  published = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
  cat_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('categories.id'))
  category = db.relationship('Category', backref='movies')

class Category(Model):
  __tablename__ = 'categories'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  title = db.Column(db.String(31), nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)
```

Comment: They have a good documentation and i did exactly like they did. But for some reason i'm still getting this kind of error

Comment: I fixed my example. I'm really sorry. Must have been absent somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my clinic relationship between the patient and patient-detail, this might help you, and it does work for me.

```
class Patient(db.Model, UserMixin): 
    __bind_key__ = 'patient'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) 
    name = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    number = db.Column(db.String(11), unique=False, nullable=False) 
    gender = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False) 
    birth = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False) 
    IDcard = db.Column(db.String(12), nullable=False) 
    age = db.Column(db.String(3), unique=False, nullable=False)
    create = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.now) 
    details = db.relationship('Detail', backref='patient', lazy=True) 

class Detail(db.Model, UserMixin): 
    __bind_key__ = 'detail'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) 
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=False)
    Symptom = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    Initial_diagnosis = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False) 
    Preliminary_treatment_plan = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False) 
    Check_result = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False) 
    Patient_reason = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=False, nullable=False) 
    Doctor_name = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=False) 
    Date_of_diagnosis = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.now)  
    detail = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('patient.id'), nullable=False)
    date_add = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.now)
```